# D3 Update vs New Item when using Key function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use D3 to display some data.  I've got an array of objects with key-value pairs.

```js
let data = [{k:'kfoo',v:'vfoo'},{k:'kbar',v:'vbar'}];

function doit(somedata){
  let bod = d3.select('body');
  let rows = bod.selectAll('div.row').data(somedata, d=>d.k);
  rows.exit().remove();
  
  let newRows = rows.enter().append('div').classed('row', true);
  newRows.append('span').text(d=>d.k);
  newRows.append('span').text(' ');
  newRows.append('span').text(d=>d.v);
  
  //rows.selectAll('span:first-child').text(d=>d.k);
  rows.selectAll('span:last-child').text(d=>d.v)
}

doit(data);

setTimeout(function(){
  data[0].k = 'kfoo1';
  data[0].v = 'vfoo1';
  doit(data);
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dfw0m1ga/1/

Why when I change the value in `data[0].k` I would expect that would result in a d3 interpreting the 0 elements as a new item.  Rather, it interprets it as an update.  Why?

Comment: Nice: a completely empty jsfiddle

Comment: read the docs about `d3.selectAll()`

Comment: Fixed the js fiddle link

Answer (score -1):

The data you modify is bound so if you modify an object the bound object is also modified and the key functions matches.

Remove the first object and add a new object.
Here it is hard coded but you can find a method that suits your real application data.

```js
let data = [{k:'kfoo',v:'vfoo'},{k:'kbar',v:'vbar'}];

function doit(somedata){
  let bod = d3.select('body');
  let rows = bod.selectAll('div.row').data(somedata, d=>d.k);
  rows.exit().remove();
  
  let newRows = rows.enter().append('div').classed('row', true);
  newRows.append('span').text(d=>d.k);
  newRows.append('span').text(' ');
  newRows.append('span').text(d=>d.v);
  
  //rows.selectAll('span:first-child').text(d=>d.k);
  rows.selectAll('span:last-child').text(d=>d.v)
}

doit(data);

setTimeout(function(){
  data = [data[1]];
  data.push( {k:'kfoo1',v:'vfoo1'} );
  doit(data);
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: within 1 minute of posting the answer I have already a down vote to an  answer that explains the reason.

Comment: If the key has changed why doesn't d3 see that as a new item thus removing the old item and adding a new item.

Comment: Read the first line of the answer.

Comment: Ah.... Its bound to the reference of the object.  Not to a copy...  This seemed to work as expected.  https://jsfiddle.net/dfw0m1ga/2/